# Can Selenium with ngwebdriver handle Angular 7+ applications for automation?

Tags: selenium, automation, protractor, angular7

Can Selenium with ngwebdriver handle Angular 7+ applications for automation?
Can you please advise difference between protractor vs ngwebdriver.

Is there any better framework for Angular 7+ applications for automation?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

What is ngWebDriver?

A small library of WebDriver locators and more for AngularJS (v1.x) and Angular (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8), for Java. It works with Firefox, Chrome and all the other Selenium-WebDriver browsers.

See https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/ngwebdriver-automating-angularjs-application-using-ankur/